# Garageband 10 pitch correction

Tags: software, garage-band, autotune

I am mixing some vocals (live recorded) with a backing track in GarageBand 10 - and there is a falsetto vocal that has a slight 'wobble' half way through.

I know you can use the pitch correction controls on a track and/or region in GarageBand, but is there a way of correcting the pitch halfway through a sung word?

I've tried splitting the region where the correction needs to take place and applying pitch correction but then you can distinctly hear where the regions start/end and I can't see anyway of blending them to sound continuous.

Any suggestions on how to 'nudge' a note so to speak?

---

N.B. *I also have Logic Pro if this of any advantage, I could drop the audio file in there and export out again if there is an easier way of achieving this...*

Comment: I haven't used the features in Logic for pitch correction but I'm fairly certain they have some.  In any event, you are much better off trying to do any sort of complicated process in Logic.  Garageband is very much a laymen's DAW, not that it can't produce a good sounding product, just doesn't have the same tools available and those that are available usually don't have as much depth.  I would suggest mixing it all in Logic, not that that has to do with your question.

Comment: @Basstickler Basically Logic Pro stopped working with the recent OS X Yosemite updates, and I wasn't paying £139.99 to upgrade just on principle which is why I've had to use GarageBand for this project. A further OS update seems to have fixed the problem and now Logic is working again for the most part. I'm not really familiar with Logic either but I'll have a look in the meantime and see what I can play with - thanks for looking!

Comment: I use Logic 9 but haven't looked for this feature in particular.  I have seen others talk about a feature in Pro Tools where you can basically draw in changes in pitch or volume.  There is definitely a lot more in Logic, which often makes it harder to find.  I thoroughly recommend trying to find some good youtube tutorials, as I have learned a lot from them.  I also experienced some issues when I upgraded to Mavericks, which I have heard Apple just told others to upgrade to resolve... I was unimpressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Logic Pro X + Flex Pitch:**

If the wobble in the note is *vibrato*, try dragging the upper-mid hotspot vertically - this will straighten out the wobble.

If you can split the note *after* the wobble without artifacts, you could then treat the wobble as pitch drift and straighten that out using the upper-right hotspot.

Try treating the wobble as a formant shift and adjusting it by dragging the lower-right hotspot vertically. This is not a likely fix but still try it - you can always undo!

**Other procedures:**

Mute the bad part of the note and carefully apply some delay/reverb to the good part of the note to extend it, masking the mistake. Create the illusion of a good note with automation.

Logic Pro X also has a suite of vocal processing effects that may help to fix this note. Try playing with the vocal transformer, pitch shifter, and pitch correction FX. I'd be surprised if you couldn't at least partially remove the offending sound in that note with these tools.

As a last resort consider punching in a good vocal. Even with live recordings this can be done with good effect if the original vocal track is somewhat isolated.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer as it closely reflects what I ended up doing at the time. The project was sat in GarageBand unfortunately and so I silenced the bad note and used reverb to smooth it over. Lesson going forward: use Logic! Thanks again :)